# Need to calculate total sub tree cost

Tags: .net, xml

```
public string CheckForGetTotalSubTreeCost(XmlDocument xdExecPlan)
{
    float totalSubtreeCost = 0;
    float subtreeCost = 0;
    int i = 0;

    XmlNodeList xnlStmtSimple = xdExecPlan.GetElementsByTagName("StmtSimple");
    XmlNode xnlStmt = xnlStmtSimple[i];
    if (xnlStmtSimple.Count > 0)
    {
        if (xnlStmt == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        foreach (XmlNode xnlStmtt in xnlStmtSimple)
        {
            if (xnlStmtSimple != null)
            {
                subtreeCost = float.Parse(xnlStmtt.Attributes[ConstantValue.STATEMENTSUBTREECOST].Value);
                totalSubtreeCost += subtreeCost;
            }
        }
```

Hi All, this function calculating total sub tree cost from the xml plan which starts from the tag StmtSimple but the thing is some StmtSimple tag has statementsubtree cost and some has i want to create a function which is having statementsubtree cost value and it adds on that which is having value.

need total subtree cost

Comment: Would you think that posting the actual XML and a complete [mcve] would be beneficial to anyone answering this question? Also, you have a long and confusing description to your problem. And, you really haven't asked us what you need.

Comment: Post xml file.  It should be very simple using Xml Linq which is the latest Net Library for xml.